# CKEditor prevent the <p> at the beginning

Tags: tags, ckeditor, paragraph

I am using CKEditor and what it does is add by default a `<p>` at the beginning of the content.

Even if I set enterMode to be `<br/>`, it will only affect what the Enter key does, and keep the starting `<p>`.

The problem I have with that is that if a text starts with an `<img>` tag, it will wrap the `<p>` around that and the `float:left` on the image has no effect anymore.

How can I stop the default `<p>` from showing please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Was looking for the answer to this question also and found this link helped: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15467&hilit=prevent+%3Cp%3E

So adding this to your config.js file works:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway of doing this from the PHP side of the config?

Comment: That the enclosing p is removed with this is only a side effect. It's actually for changing the behaviour when the user presses return.

Comment: I've tried this way, but the first p tag is still exists.. so, what should I do to change that to div or br?

Answer (score 4):

MAKE THIS YOUR config.js file code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

   //   config.enterMode = 2; //disabled <p> completely
        config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR // pressing the ENTER KEY input <br/>
        config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; //pressing the SHIFT + ENTER KEYS input <p>
        config.autoParagraph = false; // stops automatic insertion of <p> on focus
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me, put it in config.js:

```
config.enterMode = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

Comment: Please kindly add an explanation to your answer to help other readers

Comment: You might want to add some more details, code-only answer are not very useful